# Javascript AppendTo speed and a href link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wish to link different sites to the pictures. 
All I did is link the pictures to the same link.
So I want to link each pictures to the different website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

#rectangle{
width:2500px;
position:absolute;
margin-left:200px;
}

</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.crimson').css('width', 250);

                    setInterval(function () {

                $('.crimson').first().appendTo('#rectangle a' );
        }, 2000);
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="rectangle">

<a href="html/Main.html"> 
<img class="crimson"src="../pictures/CS151120.jpg"/>
<img class="crimson"  src="../pictures/CS151204.jpg" />
<img class="crimson" src="../pictures/CS151218.jpg" />
<img class="crimson" src="../pictures/CS151231.jpg" /></a>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So adding 'a' behind the appendTo rectangle is the best thing I can do.

Comment: Your question is not clear......can you ask your question tried to find it but i  failed.

Comment: where are the different website links? Are you not able to edit the markup?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping each picture in to individual `<a></a>`

`<a href="destination1"><img class="crimson"src="../pictures/CS151120.jpg"/></a>
<a href="destination2"><img class="crimson"  src="../pictures/CS151204.jpg" /></a>
<a href="destination3"><img class="crimson" src="../pictures/CS151218.jpg" /></a>
<a href="destination4"><img class="crimson" src="../pictures/CS151231.jpg" /></a>`

Comment: I tried to wrapping but did'nt work. Bunch of repeating pictures are all over the place

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.crimson').css('width', 250);

    setInterval(function () {

       // $('.crimson').first().appendTo('#rectangle a');
    }, 2000);


    $('#rectangle .crimson').each(function () {

        link = "html/Main" + $(this).index() + ".html";
        $(this).wrap("<a href='"+link+"'/>");
    });


});
```